# Set a custom extent for a layer after selecting feature?

Tags: arcpy, layers, extents

I am working on a script that will run through a variety of selections within each state. The extents are fine for all states except Hawaii and Alaska where the islands trail off and cause the feature extent to be much bigger than I want it to be. What I'm trying to do is when the script is running, once it hits Alaska, it does the selections, then zooms to a custom extent.

I've tried to use code I've found in other posts without success. Anyone have insight into how to do this?

```
def zoomToFullExtent(map_document):
DF = map_document.activeDataFrame
DF_extent = DF.extent
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(map_document, data_frame=DF):
    extent = lyr.getExtent()
    DF_extent.XMin = -20022466.14
    DF_extent.XMax = -14434454.96
    DF_extent.YMin = 6025271.58
    DF_extent.YMax = 11927735.38
DF.extent = DF_extent
```

Comment: Just want to double check- is that exactly what your code looks like? Python  requires strict indentation, try indenting everything after your function definition line--

Comment: The code above is something I pulled from another post. I'm looking for confirmation about how to do this and whether the code is something I would use for doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the example from the [ArcGIS help page](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/dataframe-class.htm), something similar to the code you've posted should work to change the *data frame extent*, not the *feature extent*. Data frame and feature extents are two different things.

```
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
newExtent = df.extent
newExtent.XMin, newExtent.YMin = [your xmin], [your ymin]
newExtent.XMax, newExtent.YMax = [your xmax], [your ymax]
df.extent = newExtent
```

Just make sure your extents are in line with the coordinate system you are using.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I didn't indent a line enough, and was using the wrong x/y values. It's working now.